# Merging tags (or setting up aliases)

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

How can I merge (or set one as alias to the other one) two tags, e.g. [numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeric) and [numerical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical)? They even have pretty much the same Wiki text.

Comment: See [What are tag synonyms? How do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work) on the über-meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think the tags mean the same thing, go to the “synonyms” tab of the tag information page for the name you want to keep, and enter the name of the tag that you want to turn into an alias in the synonym suggestion box. You need a minimum answer score in the tag.

If you don't have the requisite reputation, or if you want a second opinion from other community members, or if you want to rally support for your synonym proposal, ask here on meta.

Moderators, as usual, can make whatever synonyms they want. Moderators (and only moderators) can also merge tags. As long as tags are made synonyms but not merged, old questions will retain whatever tag name was used at the time of posting or editing, but new questions or edits will use the main tag name.

See the [tag synonyms FAQ on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work) for more information.

---

[numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeric) and [numerical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical) are a bit of a mess, including not only questions about numerical analysis but just about anything that has a number somewhere. They seem to be about equally messy, so synonymizing them wouldn't hurt. But I think it would be better to get rid of them, and stick to [numerical-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods) and [numerical-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-analysis) (which, by the way, look like they should be synonyms too).

Comment: Aye, it seems I don't have required answer scores.