# I want to consolidate all tags referencing [sikuli...] (currently 4) into one tag named [sikulix]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

I am the developer of SikuliX, that by historical reasons has its Q&A board at Launchpad. During this year, I want to move to here and phase out Launchpad.

Since Sikuli(X) exists since 2011, there are some tags here referencing Sikuli(X) in different aspects. To live my support responsibility here the same way as I can do on Launchpad, I want to consolidate those tags to one named [sikulix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sikulix) (which is the actual project name) and do that with tags, that might come up in the future by accident.

I found the tag synonyms, but it seems I am not allowed to use this feature.
What is the way to do that? It looks like I cannot do that currently without help from people having the needed privileges.

The existing tags are: [sikuli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sikuli), [sikuli-ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sikuli-ide), [sikuli-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sikuli-script) and [sikuli-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sikuli-x). For all these I want to have the synonym [sikulix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sikulix).

Comment: Could you edit your question and tell us in more detail what exactly you would like to do? Then other community members could help you in doing that. Or prevent you from doing that ;)

Comment: [some info on merging tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272145/merging-tags-or-setting-up-aliases) ;)

Comment: @honk: as mentioned: I am the developer of SikuliX, that by historical reasons has its Q&A board at Launchpad. During this year, I want to move to here and phase out Launchpad. Since Sikuli(X) exists since 2011, there are some tags here referencing Sikuli(X) in different aspects. To live my support responsibility here the same way as I can do on Launchpad, I want to consolidate those tags to one named sikulix (which is the actual project name) and do that with tags, that might come up in the future by accident.

Comment: You may want to list the tags you are referencing in your question. And additional details about the request would also be better placed in the question itself, and not in comments.

Comment: Which tags do you want to get merged? How would the sikulix tag be different from the already existing [tag:sikuli]?

Comment: Also, answers like [this](https://cl.ly/3e80dd/Image%2525202019-02-14%252520at%2525203.12.08%252520PM.png) are not really a good fit for Stack Overflow. It's great that you want to better support this on the site, but I wold advise you to better familiarize with its rules. SO and Launchpad may not have the same rules and purposes.

Comment: @BDL I think, my intention is best supported by using the actual project name sikulix (same reason why I changed the project name from Sikuli to SikuliX in 2013 - cut off the past). But I have no problem, to consolidate the other 3 tags ...-script, ...-ide and ...-x under the tag sikuli, if this is nearer to the rules and standards.

Comment: Please also note, that a lot of the lately asked questions on your launchpad are a bad fit for SO (overly broad, missing MCVE, problems related to installing sikulix but not about programming). You have to make sure that all your customers are aware that they have to ask questions that are on-topic and of good quality here. Otherwise you and your customers will have a terrible experience. You might also want to read [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: @yivy@BDL hey guys, I am just starting to get a feeling about what is possible here and what makes sense. ... and I am not a company and I do not have customers: I am developing/supporting an OSS package in my free time, that has a wide range of user types (newbees up to experts). So if you think overall the better place is launchpad, then I have no problem with that and keep my hands off from SO.

Comment: @RaiMan: It's not a generally bad idea (for the coding questions). I just wanted to make you aware that every question on SO has to follow the same quality principles, no matter if the tag is supported by the developers of a project or not. Nothing worse than moving here and noticing afterwards that SO doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you stay on Launchpad (or the opposite). Just saying that you should familiarize with SO rules before making a decision, and before jumping into supporting your technology on this site. For example, the importance of making editing questions so they have all the necessary information. Or that answers should not consist of links and follow-up questions. Reading on [what kind of question is on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (and [what kind isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)) would help you determine if this site is fit for your purposes.

Comment: @BDL@yivi: thanks for your helpful comments - all read and understood. Launchpad surely does not have such a well defined rule set like SO, that try to teach the users how to ask good questions. So yes, I have to make my experiences as well as my users have to. But that leaves me alone with my initial request: Who can help me, to consolidate the tags?

Comment: You need a number of users with a certain score in a tag to add a new synonym. For smaller tags this can be difficult so a moderator can apply them instead, posting this Meta question was the right thing to do.

Comment: @RaiMan I'm not adverse to syn'ing/merging such tags but as community members have mentioned - you need to make sure SO is the right place for things you're looking at and also - I'm not entirely convinced it's necessary right now. Could you possibly add a bit more explanation of why this is something that should be done now rather something that could be done later organically?

Comment: Please also read [the help center topic on product support](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support).

Answer (score 6):

Thanks all for the valuable comments.

After having read all the mentioned stuff and more, I decided, to leave everything for now as is.

I have registered filters for the mentioned tags and get a daily mail on the activities. So I can come here if needed and get more acquainted to the SO world over the time.

Comment: Feel free to leave this post about... there's some important points made here in the comments and it'll serve as a reference for later discussion should the query need re-addressing.

Comment: I added a [status-declined] on the post, as it seems like you have found a way to solve your issues without synonymization.